# Spring MultipartResolver is not configured

Tags: spring, hibernate, file, jsp, upload

I want to upload files to a folder in my project. But when I select a file and click the upload button I get the following error:
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?

This is my MultipartResolver bean:

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" 
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</beans:bean>
```

This is my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UploadController {
private String folderTujuanUpload="/uploads";
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/form",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void tampilkanFormUpload(){}


 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload/form",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String prosesFormUpload(HttpSession session, @RequestParam("filegambar") MultipartFile                   hasilUpload) throws IOException{

String lokasiUpload = tujuanUpload(session).getAbsolutePath();     

 LOGGER.debug("name File [{}]",hasilUpload.getName());
 LOGGER.debug("Size File [{}]",hasilUpload.getSize()); 
 LOGGER.debug("Type File [{}]",hasilUpload.getContentType());

 File tujuan = new File(lokasiUpload + File.separator + hasilUpload.getOriginalFilename());
 try{
     hasilUpload.transferTo(tujuan);   
 }catch (Exception ex) {
     LOGGER.error("cant upload file");
     LOGGER.error("Penyebab : {}", ex.getMessage());
 }
     return "redirect:list";
 }





 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload/list")
 public ModelMap tampilkanhasilUpload(){
     ModelMap mm=new ModelMap();
     return mm;
 }
 private File tujuanUpload(HttpSession session){
     String lokasiFullPath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath(folderTujuanUpload);
     LOGGER.debug("lokasi full path : [{}]",lokasiFullPath);

     File hasil = new File(lokasiFullPath);
     if (!hasil.exists())
     {
         LOGGER.debug("lokasiblabla");
     hasil.mkdirs();
     }
     return hasil;
 }
```

}

And this are the jsp pages i have:

form.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>form upload</h1>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>pilla palla </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="filegambar">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                        
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Üpload">
                    </td>
                </tr>     
            </tbody>                
        </table>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

list.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hassandsjaiadsf upload</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the following. Do you have the commons-fileupload dependency?

Comment: yes, i have the dependency. But I just found out that I never redirect to the servlet file where the beans are in. Do you have any idea how i should do that?

Comment: Where is the `MultipartResolver` bean declared?